# I am getting an error while installing pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Python 3.9 64 bit, I am encountering an error while installing pyinstaller. How can I resolve this error?

Trying to download Pyinstaller to convert Python files to .exe.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fy00R.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to install wheel before:

```
pip install wheel
```

Comment: @DoğukanÜrker Glad it helped! And welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted :)